# aws cdk application load balancer fails to create with error missing required parameters for default actions

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sdk, aws-cdk

I have created a default listener, the cdk docs suggest that only property Type and TargetGroupArn are required fields.

```
var listener_defaults = new List<CfnListener.ActionProperty>();
            listener_defaults.Add(new CfnListener.ActionProperty()
                                    {Type="forward",
                                    TargetGroupArn = targetGroup.LogicalId 
                                    });
```

The execution fails with the error...

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/Amazon.JSII.Runtime.JsiiException
An unhandled exception of type 'Amazon.JSII.Runtime.JsiiException' occurred in Amazon.JSII.Runtime.dll: '**Missing required properties for @aws-cdk/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2.CfnListenerProps: defaultActions**'
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.Client.TryDeserialize[TResponse](String responseJson)
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.Client.ReceiveResponse[TResponse]()
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Deputy.DeputyBase..ctor(DeputyProps props)
   at InfraPlatform.stacks.AlbStack..ctor(Construct parent, String id, IStackProps props) in
```

I am using AWS CDK, csharp flavour of it... It is likely that this could be a bug in the skd (I am using cdk version 1.13.1 (build 96cfc63)). Any suggestions on how I can troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Documentation link? Are you creating a classic load balancer or Application load balancer?

Comment: The link to the documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticloadbalancingv2-listener-defaultactions.html 

This is an Application Load Balancer.